# React keeps throwing index error even though I have indexes defined

Tags: reactjs

I am building some JSX with a map() and know full well about setting keys on list items.  However, React keeps throwing this error:

```
index.js:2177 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `DocsNavbar`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys for more information.
    in Fragment (created by DocsNavbar)
    in DocsNavbar (at layoutDocs.js:32)
    in LayoutHome (at docs.js:26)
    in DocsPage (created by HotExportedDocsPage)
    in AppContainer (created by HotExportedDocsPage)
    in HotExportedDocsPage (created by PageRenderer)
    in PageRenderer (at query-result-store.js:86)
    in PageQueryStore (at root.js:56)
    in RouteHandler (at root.js:78)
    in div (created by FocusHandlerImpl)
    in FocusHandlerImpl (created by Context.Consumer)
    in FocusHandler (created by RouterImpl)
    in RouterImpl (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Location (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Router (created by EnsureResources)
    in ScrollContext (at root.js:69)
    in RouteUpdates (at root.js:68)
    in EnsureResources (at root.js:66)
    in LocationHandler (at root.js:124)
    in LocationProvider (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Location (at root.js:123)
    in Root (at root.js:132)
    in StaticQueryStore (at root.js:138)
    in _default (at app.js:67)
```

Here is the `DocsNavbar` component the stack trace is referring to.  The problem is specifically with the `<h2>` tag, because if I take it out, the error goes away.

```
  return (
    <>
      <MenuMobile menuItems={menuItems} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />
      <Navbar bg="white" variant="light" expand="lg" fixed="left">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/home">
          <img src={logo} width="113" height="40" alt={siteTitle + " Logo"} />
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <NavbarToggler open={open} setOpen={setOpen} />

        <Accordion activeKey={active} className="sidebar-menu" onSelect={(e) => setActive(e)}>
          {menu.groups.map((group, i) => {
            return (
              <>
                <h2 className="group-title" key={group.title.toLowerCase()} data-key={group.title.toLowerCase()}>
                  {group.title}
                </h2>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </Accordion>
      </Navbar>
    </>
  );
```

I outputted the key value as a data attribute to double-check it and you can see from the rendered output, each key is unique:

```
<div class="sidebar-menu accordion">
  <h2 class="group-title" data-key="general">General</h2>
  <h2 class="group-title" data-key="solutions">Solutions</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:** You've placed keys on the descendants of each child.

**Solution:** React keys need to be on the outer most element mapped, in this case, the Fragment. You need to actually specify the `Fragment` tag as attributes won't work with the shorthand notation.

```
{menu.groups.map(group => {
  return (
    <Fragment key={group.title.toLowerCase()} >
      <h2 className="group-title" data-key={group.title.toLowerCase()}>
        {group.title}
      </h2>
    </Fragment>
  );
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
       return (
          <div key={i}>
            <h2 className="group-title" key={group.title.toLowerCase()} data-key={group.title.toLowerCase()}>
              {group.title}
            </h2>
          </div>
        );
```

Comment: ugh, so i have to convert the fragment to an element? i'm trying not to add more markup.